# What kind of Mersenne Twister is being used in numpy.randomState?

Tags: numpy, random, mersenne-twister

Is numpy.random.RandomState using MT19937 or something else? All the document said was Mersenne Twister, and while I saw a few legacy ones uing MT19937, I never saw a straight answer.

Thank you!

Comment: `np.random.get_state()[0] ` and/or `np.random.RandomState()`.  Note there were major changes in 1.17.

Comment: The current docs mention `MT19937`, not the `Twister`.

Comment: As pointed out, the documentation of the now legacy [`RandomState`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/legacy.html) does mention that it uses a MT19937 generator. In the new [`Generator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/generator.html) class, you can choose between different [bit generators](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/bit_generators/index.html).

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear in my question. I meant to ask which version of MT19937 (since it seems like there's a number of versions on the original website for MT19937) was implemented.